# (scheme) How to add elements in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, scheme

This function is supposed to find the sum of each row and put it in a list. I thought something like this would work but it doesn't. It gives me a weird output.

Like, if I have a matrix that has two rows and two columns of 1's, it returns this:

```
(2 . 1)
```

Instead of this:

```
(2 2)
```

Help?

```
(define (sum mat)
  (let loop ([r 0]
         [c 0])
   (if (> r (matrix-rows mat)) '()
      (if (>= c (sub1 (matrix-cols mat))) (add1 r)
         (cons (+ (matrix-ref mat r c) (matrix-ref mat r (add1 c))) (loop r (add1 c)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `(add1 r)` you should call `(loop (+ r 1) 0)`.  Note: this suggestion is correct; however, there are likely other errors in your code, specifically your computation with the matrix-ref calls doesn't look like it will add up a row.  You can see that by testing with a matrix of more than two rows.

Here is a fix:

```
(define (sum mat)
  (let loop ((r 0) (c 0) (s 0) (a '())   ;; row, col, sum, ans
    (cond ((>= r (matrix-rows mat)) (reverse a))
          ((>= c (matrix-cols mat)) (loop (+ r 1) 0 0 (cons s a)))
          (else (loop r (+ c 1) (+ s (matrix-ref mat r c)) a)))))
```